# Getting DEM data programmatically with libgdal?

Tags: gdal, dem, geotiff-tiff, c

I'm writing a specialized tool in C to work with DEM data (typically GeoTIFF files, but one of the reasons I'm using libgdal is to leverage its ability to read multiple formats).

I'm able to open a GeoTIFF file and get at some of the metadata, but how do I get at the elevation data (e.g., given a pixel location, get the height) programmatically?

Perhaps I need to index into the raw raster data myself.

Comment: Have a look at the [GDAL API Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html#gdal_tutorial_read), and perhaps the source of [`gdallocationinfo`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `GDALRasterBand::RasterIO`. For efficiency, if you are indexing multiple points, you will want to read data in blocks then index into the resulting array